# Brew update php56-xdebug requires changing zend_extension path in php.ini manually. Can it be scripted instead?

Tags: php, bash, homebrew, xdebug

I've installed php56-xdebug (along with php56, naturally) using homebrew and I've made the requisite addition to my php.ini

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php56-xdebug/2.3.2/xdebug.so"
```

Today I did a `brew update && upgrade` which updated my `php56-xdebug` to version `2.3.3` This, of course, changed the directory listing of the xdebug.so file to `/usr/local/Cellar/php56-xdebug/2.3.3/xdebug.so`

I'd love to find a way to update that automatically whenever it changes after a brew update/upgrade. Alas, I'm not knowledgeable enough in bash to know how to make this happen. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply always use the symbolic links that Homebrew maintains for you inside `/usr/local/opt`:

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php56-xdebug/xdebug.so"
```

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew always creates a symlink to the most recent version in `/usr/local/bin` or in your case, since it is a lib, in `/usr/local/lib`. Just use this path in your php.ini and it should be fine.

Comment: It was in /usr/local/opt... Thank you.